# Nightwatch attributeContains with multiple acceptable values

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a successful test

```html
browser
      .url(testURL)
      .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000)
      .verify.attributeContains('someElement', 'someAttribute', 'foo')
```

But for my purposes it is acceptable for 'someAttribute' to contain 'foo' OR 'bar'. I'm wondering how I can write this kind of test so that no test failures are reported by Nightwatch.

Answer (score 3):

You can test if attribute contains 'foo' OR 'bar' in two steps:

1. get the attribute value with [`getAttribute()`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getAttribute) or [`attribute()`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-attribute)
2. match a regex against the value

With `getAttribute()`, use [`regex.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
browser.getAttribute('someElement', 'someAttribute', function(result) {
    this.assert.value(/foo|bar/.test(result.value), true);
};
```

With `attribute()`, use `matches()` assertion:

```
browser.expect.element('someElement').to.have.attribute('someAttribute')
    .which.matches(/foo|bar/);
```

Answer (score 0):

use .elements() and obtain the length of element result to avoid fail message.

```
.elements('css selector','someElement[yourattribute="foo"]',function(result){
    if(result.value.length>0){ //element exists 
       console.log('somelement is here')  
    }
    else{
      console.log('not here')
    }  
});
```